# Php spreadsheet downlod is giving garbage collect error

Tags: php-8.1, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet, symfony5.4

I am using `"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.25",` for downloading Excel file.

Here is the code I have used.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

class ExcelDownload
{
    public function export(): StreamedResponse
    {
        $spreadSheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Order Export');
        $sheet->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(16)->setBold(true);

        $writer = new Xlsx($sheet);

        $response = new StreamedResponse();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
        $response->headers->set(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment;filename=OrderExport.xlsx'
        );
        $response->headers->set(
            'Cache-Control',
            'max-age=0'
        );

        $response->setCallback(function () use ($writer): void {
            $writer->save('php://output');
        });

        return $response;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet::garbageCollect() must be compatible with PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet::garbageCollect(): void
```

Can anybody please help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For **xlsx**, I use `Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

For **xls**, I use `Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel`

For **pdf**, I use `Content-type: application/pdf`

Here the official [reference](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#redirect-output-to-a-clients-web-browser).

Hope it helps!